# Flutter Bool Data in Post Object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a post object. Like Below.

```
{
       "facilities": value.join(","),
       "start_date": startDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "end_date": endDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "over_ratio": false,
       "total": true
}
```

I send this object in body, but server send me `404` message. but When I write my `bool` data like `"over_ratio": "false", "total": "true"`, server understands this `bool` data wrong.

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
     print(response.body);
    }
```

I need to send this bodys `bool` data like:

```
{
       "facilities": value.join(","),
       "start_date": startDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "end_date": endDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "over_ratio": false,
       "total": true
}
```

I also tried like, but same problem occurs:

```
json.encode({
       "facilities": value.join(","),
       "start_date": startDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "end_date": endDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
       "over_ratio": false,
       "total": true
});
```

How can I send this post correctly ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem like this.

```
Map<String, String> get headers =>
      {"Authorization": "Bearer $token", "Content-Type": "application/json"};
```

My old header data like this below.

```
Map<String, String> get headers =>
          {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"}
```

And I also did my json data like below with `jsonEncode()`.

```
jsonEncode({
              "facilities": value.join(","),
              "start_date": startDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
              "end_date": endDate.toString().substring(0, 10),
              "over_ratio": false,
              "total": true
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to post data with **`jsonEncode(body)`**

Hope it will work.

Comment: No. Your code does not work. Same problem is continue